# how to create a json enclosed with square brackets in java?

Tags: json, gson

I generate a json with the following code.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("Message","All");
list.add(map);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String userResponseListValue = gson.toJson(map);
```

I get the json in the following format

```
   {"Message":"All"}
```

I need the json to be in the following format

```
   [{"Message":"All"}]
```

Since I'm new to gson i can't fix this problem. can some one guide me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets denote a list or array, so try outputting the `list` you already prepared but are not using:

```
gson.toJson(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Brackets `[]` denote an `Array` in JSON, and what you have is a `HashMap`, not an `Array`...

You can manually add the square brackets like:

```
String userResponseListValue = "[ " + gson.toJson(map) + " ]";
```

Or create a `ArrayList<HashMap>`.

**EDIT**: In fact, you have the `Array`, but you're not using it! Try:

```
String userResponseListValue = gson.toJson(list);
```